# Determine if $\sum \frac{1}{(\ln{n})^{\ln{n}}}$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I currently trying to determine it by comparison. I've tried comparing it with $\frac{1}{n^2}$, and it seems to work but I'm not sure if I did it right.

I've done it like this:

$(\ln {n})^{\ln{n}}>n^2$

$e^{\ln{\ln{n}}\times\ln{n}}>e^{\ln{n}\times2}$

$\ln{\ln{n}}\times\ln{n}>\ln{n}\times2$

$\ln{\ln{n}}>2$

$n>e^{(e^2)}$

So I assume this is enough? A convergent series is greater than the original one after some constant $m$. Anything else I need?

Comment: Yes, you are done!

Comment: Well that's fantastic!

Comment: Yep! And it's about 5.717 for what it's worth.

Comment: Is there a way to calculate the actual value or do you just approximate by adding up the first few members?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test for convergence of the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{(\ln n)^{\ln n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652345/test-for-convergence-of-the-series-sum-n-2-infty-frac1-ln-n-ln-n)

Comment: @LukaHorvat I understand that $$n>e^{e^2}$$ implies $$ln(n)^{ln(n)}>n^2$$. But how do you know that $$ln(n)^{ln(n)}>n^2$$ is true to begin with?

Comment: @PGupta We don't. That's what we're proving. We use a series of algebraic manipulations to show that if $n>e^{(e^2)}$ then $(\ln {n})^{\ln{n}}>n^2$. And since $e^{(e^2)}$ is a constant, $n$ will be greater than it after some point, hence $(\ln {n})^{\ln{n}}>n^2$ will hold.

Comment: Then, how do you know that taking n>e^e^2  will give ln n ^ ln n > n^2?

Comment: @PGupta You said yourself that you understand how the first inequality implies the second. So if the first is true, the second is also true.

Comment: Either you start by assuming n>e^e^2 or you start by assuming ln n^ln n>n^2. If you are assuming the former, how do you know to choose e^e^2 as the bound on n? Do you 'guess' it? If I ask you about the convergence of series ( ln n )^e^n, will you be able to guess how large n should be? (Sorry if I'm sounding dumb!)

Comment: @PGupta You "start" from n>e^e^2 but you don't guess it. If you had to prove $n^2 > 2n$, you'd divide by $n$ to get $n>2$ which is true (after 2). Did you guess $n>2$? No, you just manipulate the original inequality with valid algebraic transformations until you get something obviously true. In my question I do the same thing. First I change the base to $e$, then I apply the natural logarithm, then divide by $\ln n$ and finally I exponentiate twice.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{(\log n)^{\log n}}=e^{-\log n(\log(\log n))}=\frac{1}{n^{\log(\log n)}}\leq\frac{1}{n^2}$$
for large $n$, hence the given series is convergent by comparison.

Comment: You are making mistake, $e^{(\log n)(\log\log n)}=n^{\log \log n}$.

Comment: You're claiming that $(\log n)^{\log n} = n \log \log n$. Surely that's incorrect.

Comment: It's still incorrect though.

Comment: Finally the conclusion is right. (But the last inequality only holds for sufficiently large $n$.)

Comment: Now it is correct, modulo taking $n$ large enough. But note that it is exactly the OP's argument...

Comment: How do you show the last inequality?

Answer (score 2):

What about the condensation test?

$$2^na_{2^n}=\frac{2^n}{\left(\log2^n\right)^{\log 2^n}}=\frac{2^n}{n^{n\log 2}\left(\log2\right)^{n\log 2}}$$

And now apply the $\,n$-th root test to the above:

$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{2^n}{n^{n\log 2}\left(\log2\right)^{n\log 2}}}=\frac2{n^{log2}\left(\log2\right)^{\log2}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

Thus, $\,\sum 2^na_{2^n}\;$ converges $\,\iff\sum a_n\;$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

We can use [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) to obtain the condensed series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{2^n}{(\ln{2^n})^{\left(\ln{2^n}\right)}}=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty }\frac{2^n}{[(n\ln 2)^{\ln 2}]^n}$$

then observe that eventually

$$(n\ln 2)^{\ln 2} \ge3 \implies \frac{2^n}{[(n\ln 2)^{\ln 2}]^n} \le \left(\frac23\right)^n$$