# Test for convergence of the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{(\ln n)^{\ln n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Could I have a hint for testing the convergence of the following series please?

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{(\ln n)^{\ln n}}$$

*Edit*

The integral test does not work because $\int_1^n\frac{1}{(\ln x)^{\ln x}}dx$ has not an elementary primitive.

Thank You.

Comment: did you try the integral test?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore's_dream

Comment: @Alex I'm trying with the integral test, but this integral is really tough for me... I'll check your link now! Thank you for your help man; I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Alex Am I on the right way? Can this integral be reduced to a simple one?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408824/determine-if-sum-frac1-lnn-lnn-converges

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Alternate hint:

$$
(\ln n)^{\ln n} = n^{\ln \ln n}.
$$

Comment: Thank you. I did it with the comparison test.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: I have never seen this before, how do you get to that equation?

Comment: @KitKat, take $\ln$ of $(\ln n)^{\ln n}$ to get $(\ln n)\ln\ln n$, rewrite this as $\ln(n^{\ln\ln n})$, then exponentiate this to get $n^{\ln \ln n}$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Nice, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Consider

$$
2^k \frac{1}{(k\ln e)^{k\ln 2}}>\sum_{2^k\le n< 2^{k+1}} \frac{1}{(\ln n)^{\ln n}}> 2^k\frac{1}{((k+1)\ln e)^{(k+1)\ln 2}},
$$