# Where is this proof wrong (convergence of a logarithmic series)?

Tags: real-analysis

I have the series

$\sum_{n \ge 3} \frac{1}{(\ln{n})^{\ln{n}}}$

I proved it diverges, but I am pretty sure it converges.

Here is what I do:

$\sum_{n \ge 3} \frac{1}{(\ln{n})^{\ln{n}}} \ge \sum_{n \ge 3} \frac{1}{\ln{n}} \ge \sum_{n \ge 3} \frac{1}{n}$

Thus it diverges by comparison criterion.

My reasoning for the first inequality was $\ln n \ge \ln 3 \ge \ln e$

My reasoning for the second was $\ln n \le n$

Answer (score 1):

Your inequalities are reversed.  Note that $\log(n)^{\log(n)}\ge \log(n)$ for $n\ge 3$.  So, we have

$$\frac1{\log(n)^{\log(n)}}\le \frac1{\log(n)}$$

See [THIS POST](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652345/test-for-convergence-of-the-series-sum-n-2-infty-frac1-ln-n-ln-n) for proof on convergence.

Answer (score 1):

Your first inequality is incorrect. It is not true that $\ln(n)^{\ln(n)}\leq \ln(n)^1$ holds for all  $n$.

Here is a hint towards one approach to proving convergence. Note that
$$
(\ln(n))^{\ln(n)} = (e^{\ln(\ln(n))})^{\ln(n)} = (e^{\ln(n)})^{\ln(\ln(n))} = n^{\ln(\ln(n))}.
$$